# Hashcat to mask recover variable length password with known suffix

Tags: hashcat

I'm struggling with creating a mask to brute-force using Hashcat a password of variable length, but with a known suffix.

Say the known suffix is `123$` but the variable-length "prefix" can contain between 4 and 7 characters (i.e. total length 8 to 11 characters)

Do I need to define a charset? I'm aware of "increment mode", but how do I stipulate a variable length mask - looking at examples it seems to only let me define each character independently, how would this work with a variable length?

Answer (score 2):

You won't need to define a charset if your password uses one of the included ones.

You should use a `.hcmask` file to define your different lengths.

Like this:

```
?a?a?a?a123$
?a?a?a?a?a123$
?a?a?a?a?a?a123$
?a?a?a?a?a?a?a123$
```

There are 96 characters in `?a`, so 96⁴ + 96⁵ + 96⁶ + 96⁷ ≈ 2⁴⁶ hash computations are necessary, which would require 10 to 20 minutes at 70 GH/s.